# Can't i initialized empty String array and pass in the value afterwards in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seems to find out what what is wrong with my codes? i can't pass in non-empty String value into an empty String array?

```
String[] profiles = wifiPositioningServices.GetAllProfileData();

ArrayList<String[]> macAddresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] macAddressTemp=null;

    //store all profile data into a ArrayList of Profile objects
    for(int i=0; i<profiles.length; i++){
        String[] result = profiles[i].split(",");
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileName(result[0]);
        profile.setOwner(result[1]);
        profile.setMap(result[2]);
        profile.setVisible(result[3]);
        boolean visible = Boolean.valueOf(result[3]);
        if(visible){
            //if visible is true, then add profile name and mac filters into arraylist 
            profileNames.add(result[0]);
            int cnt=0;
            for(int j=4; j<result.length; j++){
                profile.setMacFiltersList(result[j]);
                Log.e("Text:", result[j]);
                macAddressTemp[cnt] = result[j];
                ++cnt;
            }
            macAddresses.add(macAddressTemp);
        }
        profileList.add(profile);
    }
```

Java show a nullpointer exception at the line "macAddressTemp[cnt] = result[j];". I am sure that result[j] is not empty cause i was able to print it out via the log msg.

Comment: You're code is wrong. Check my answer bellow. Go Pumas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

```
ArrayList<String> macAddressTemp = new ArrayList<String>(100); //check capacity
macAddressTemp.add(result[j]);
```

**EDIT**:

You changed your code wrong.
This `ArrayList<String[]> macAddresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();` is creating a List that contains arrays. You have to create a List that contains String. Check the code above.

Comment: i guess i just have to revert back to my previous method which is to store the list of mac addresses i retrieved in the arrayList in the Profile object.

Answer (score 1):

The array `macAddressTemp` is null.

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is thrown because `macAddressTemp` is `null`. You probably want to declare and initialize `macAddressTemp` inside of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly set it to null:

```
String[] macAddressTemp=null;
```

You need to allocate some *space* for the array, or use a collection.